# filter and map in an object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't retrieve the user by his customer number. I use the includes function in filter, but this returns the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes') . Despite everything I've seen on the forum, nothing solves my problem. I have an array of user object, so I make a map on the array and then I filter here is my code:

thank you very much for help

```
const ClientComponent = ()=>{
   const resultSearchClient = useSelector((state)=> state.reducerSearchCriteria)
   const datasClientService = useSelector((state)=> state.reducerClientAdmin.state)
   const newArray = datasClientService.map(val=>{ return val})
   const filterArray = newArray.filter(u => {return u.number_client.includes(resultSearchClient)})
  
   return(
     <div>
       <p>{filterArray} </p>
    </div>
 )
}

export default ClientComponent;
```

Comment: @AhmadFaraz, why would that help??

Comment: so that means one of your users in `newArray` does not have a defined `number_client`

Comment: thank you very much to all for your contribution, the solution is a little further down from @Cristian-Florin Calina

Comment: @trincot `FilterArray` may not exist, and the components render first, so I'll just check if `filterArray` exists, then `filterArray` will be displayed, and `u.number_client.includes(resultSearchClient)` will also need to be changed `u.number_client? .includes(resultSearchClient)`and check that `number_client` exists so that your code runs and your app doesn't crash.

Comment: @AhmadFaraz, `.filter()` **always** returns an array when there is no exception, so it is useless to do what you suggest. The asker's problem is indeed *earlier* in the code, where an exception occurs, which can be solved with the `?.`  operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are receiving is thrown because `number_client` is null (instead of an array or string that you are expecting there).
If you know that `number_client` is nullish, you can do:

```js
const filterArray = newArray.filter(u => 
  return (u.number_client ?? '').includes(resultSearchClient)
})
```

If you expect a value everytime there, then there is a different problem with your data.

Also, what is the purpose of `newArray`? that map does nothing except for creating a shallow clone, right? If you neeed a shallow clone, you can just do `const newArray = [...datasClientService]`. But from what you sent here, `newArray` is not even needed. You can just create `filterArray` based on `dataClientService` since `Array.filter` method returns a new array.

Comment: Great thank you very much your solution works @Cristian-Florin Calina. New array is used to display all customers when I arrive on the page